# Get First and last day of a month based on a combobox

Tags: vb.net

My question is how to get the first and last day of a month into a text boxes based on a combo box.

For Example, My combo box has values like "December-2016", "January-2017", if i choose "December-2016" i want to get "01/12/2016" "31/12/2016"

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: My question is *what have you tried*?  Please read [ask] and also take the [Tour]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you both dates. Just replace the static date I used with your combobox value.

```
Dim dt As Date
If Date.TryParse("December-2016", dt) Then
  Dim startDt As New Date(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1)
  Dim endDt As New Date(dt.Year, dt.Month, Date.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month))
End If
```